# How to align links within an <li> to the bottom?

Tags: css

Here's my CSS, I like to make the links within the *li* set to the bottom. I tried vertical bottom on the links, but it's a no go.

```
.textResizer {
list-style-type: none;
float: right;
width: 85px;
height: 30px;
margin: 6px 12px -6px 0px;
padding: 0;
}

.textResizer li {
float:left;
margin-left:10px;
}

.textResizer a {
color:#1a5c88;
text-decoration:none;

}

.textResizer .small a{
font-size:.75em;
font-weight:bold;   
 }

.textResizer .medium a{
font-size:1em;
font-weight:bold;   
 }

 .textResizer .large a{
font-size:1.3em;
font-weight:bold;   
 }
```

Here are the links in action, http://jsfiddle.net/HN7Hy/ thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

One way could be to set list items as `inline-block` instead of `float: left`:
http://jsfiddle.net/HN7Hy/2/